# Clean, efficient way to modify external table without modifying internal tables

Tags: tables, tabularx, parameters, css

Oftentimes the best way I can figure out how to lay out something is with the mindset I learned from HTML, tables within tables.  How can I modify parameters affecting the external table without affecting the internal tables?

For example, suppose I want to do the MWE below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=0.50in, right=0.50in, top=0.50in, bottom=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lXX}
    Short Title &
    Longer sentence giving a description of the thing to the right. &
    \({
    \begin{bmatrix}
        a & a & a & a \\
        a & a & a & a \\
        a & a & a & a \\
        a & a & a & a
    \end{bmatrix}
    \begin{bmatrix}
        b & b & b & b \\
        b & b & b & b \\
        b & b & b & b \\
        b & b & b & b
    \end{bmatrix}
    =
    \begin{bmatrix}
        c & c & c & c \\
        c & c & c & c \\
        c & c & c & c \\
        c & c & c & c
    \end{bmatrix}
    }\) \\
    Another line &
    That is like the one above. &
    \({
    \begin{bmatrix}
        a & a & a & a \\
        a & a & a & a \\
        a & a & a & a \\
        a & a & a & a
    \end{bmatrix}
    \begin{bmatrix}
        b & b & b & b \\
        b & b & b & b \\
        b & b & b & b \\
        b & b & b & b
    \end{bmatrix}
    =
    \begin{bmatrix}
        c & c & c & c \\
        c & c & c & c \\
        c & c & c & c \\
        c & c & c & c
    \end{bmatrix}
    }\)
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Clearly I want more space between the rows and columns of the outer table, without affecting the inner ones (which sometimes are `tabular` instead of `bmatrix`). Sometimes I want to tweak all the inner tables without affecting the outer one.

Is there a clean way to do this, without peppering commands all throughout?  Like, is there a CSS style method where I could define a table class and then specify that the outer table is of some class different than the regular ones?

---

## Update

Here's another example.  Using egreg's answer below, I have to put in 2(r-1) instances of `\addlinespace`, and it interrupts the vertical lines.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}


\begin{alignat*}{4}
    &
    \left[
    \begin{array}{c|c}
        \begin{bmatrix}
            a & b
        \end{bmatrix}
        \begin{bmatrix}
            w \\ y
        \end{bmatrix}
        &
        \begin{bmatrix}
            a & b
        \end{bmatrix}
        \begin{bmatrix}
            x \\ z
        \end{bmatrix}
        \\ \hline
        \begin{bmatrix}
            c & d
        \end{bmatrix}
        \begin{bmatrix}
            w \\ y
        \end{bmatrix}
        &
        \begin{bmatrix}
            c & d
        \end{bmatrix}
        \begin{bmatrix}
            x \\ z
        \end{bmatrix}
        \\ \hline
        \begin{bmatrix}
            e & f
        \end{bmatrix}
        \begin{bmatrix}
            w \\ y
        \end{bmatrix}
        &
        \begin{bmatrix}
            e & f
        \end{bmatrix}
        \begin{bmatrix}
            x \\ z
        \end{bmatrix}
    \end{array}
    \right]
    &&
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
    \left[
    \begin{array}{c|c}
        \begin{bmatrix}
            a & b
        \end{bmatrix}
        \begin{bmatrix}
            w \\ y
        \end{bmatrix}
        &
        \begin{bmatrix}
            a & b
        \end{bmatrix}
        \begin{bmatrix}
            x \\ z
        \end{bmatrix}
        \\ \hline
        \begin{bmatrix}
            c & d
        \end{bmatrix}
        \begin{bmatrix}
            w \\ y
        \end{bmatrix}
        &
        \begin{bmatrix}
            c & d
        \end{bmatrix}
        \begin{bmatrix}
            x \\ z
        \end{bmatrix}
        \\ \hline
        \begin{bmatrix}
            e & f
        \end{bmatrix}
        \begin{bmatrix}
            w \\ y
        \end{bmatrix}
        &
        \begin{bmatrix}
            e & f
        \end{bmatrix}
        \begin{bmatrix}
            x \\ z
        \end{bmatrix}
    \end{array}
    \right]
    &&
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1}
    \left[
    \begin{array}{c|c}
        \begin{bmatrix}
            a & b
        \end{bmatrix}
        \begin{bmatrix}
            w \\ y
        \end{bmatrix}
        &
        \begin{bmatrix}
            a & b
        \end{bmatrix}
        \begin{bmatrix}
            x \\ z
        \end{bmatrix}
        \\ \addlinespace \hline \addlinespace
        \begin{bmatrix}
            c & d
        \end{bmatrix}
        \begin{bmatrix}
            w \\ y
        \end{bmatrix}
        &
        \begin{bmatrix}
            c & d
        \end{bmatrix}
        \begin{bmatrix}
            x \\ z
        \end{bmatrix}
        \\ \addlinespace \hline \addlinespace
        \begin{bmatrix}
            e & f
        \end{bmatrix}
        \begin{bmatrix}
            w \\ y
        \end{bmatrix}
        &
        \begin{bmatrix}
            e & f
        \end{bmatrix}
        \begin{bmatrix}
            x \\ z
        \end{bmatrix}
    \end{array}
    \right]
    &&
    \left[
    \begin{array}{c|c}
        \begin{bmatrix}
            a & b
        \end{bmatrix}
        \begin{bmatrix}
            w \\ y
        \end{bmatrix}
        &
        \begin{bmatrix}
            a & b
        \end{bmatrix}
        \begin{bmatrix}
            x \\ z
        \end{bmatrix}
        \\[12pt] \hline
        \begin{bmatrix}
            c & d
        \end{bmatrix}
        \begin{bmatrix}
            w \\ y
        \end{bmatrix}
        &
        \begin{bmatrix}
            c & d
        \end{bmatrix}
        \begin{bmatrix}
            x \\ z
        \end{bmatrix}
        \\[12pt] \hline \\[12pt]
        \begin{bmatrix}
            e & f
        \end{bmatrix}
        \begin{bmatrix}
            w \\ y
        \end{bmatrix}
        &
        \begin{bmatrix}
            e & f
        \end{bmatrix}
        \begin{bmatrix}
            x \\ z
        \end{bmatrix}
    \end{array}
    \right]
    \\
    &\text{No changes.}&
    &
    \begin{array}{l}
        \text{\textbackslash arraystretch} \\ \text{changes everything}
    \end{array}
    &
    &\text{Using \textbackslash addlinespace.}&
    &\begin{array}{l}
            \text{Nope.} \\ \text{and O.M.G.!!}
    \end{array}
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I just want to be able to do something like (pseudocode):

```
define OuterRowAndColSpacing

\begin{OuterArrayOrTable}[OuterRowAndColSpacing]
    \begin{InnerMatrix}
        ...
    \end{InnerMatrix}
    ...
\end{OuterArrayOrTable}
```

and have everything just work.

(Today is one of those of those days when I'm just like: You're getting a Word document, and you're going to accept it, and you're going to like it!)

Comment: Changes made inside a "group" are local to the group.  {...} is a group.  You would need at least one custom macro to specify all the parameters (\arraystretch, \arraycolsep, \baselineskip) for each group.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I've tried this route, but the problem is that the inner tables are also inside the group that the outer table is in, so changes to the outer table also affect the inner ones.

Comment: I think it's better if you comment @egreg's answer to draw his attention or ask a new question with reference to the old one, rather than edit it. I don't think many people read the edit of an already-answered question.

Answer (score 2):

Explicitly set the intercolumn space:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=0.50in, right=0.50in, top=0.50in, bottom=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{
  @{}% no left padding
  l
  @{\hspace{2cm}}% more padding (exaggerated)
  X
  @{\qquad}% more padding
  X
  @{}% no right padding
}
    Short Title &
    Longer sentence giving a description of the thing to the right. &
    \(
    \begin{bmatrix}
        a & a & a & a \\
        a & a & a & a \\
        a & a & a & a \\
        a & a & a & a
    \end{bmatrix}
    \begin{bmatrix}
        b & b & b & b \\
        b & b & b & b \\
        b & b & b & b \\
        b & b & b & b
    \end{bmatrix}
    =
    \begin{bmatrix}
        c & c & c & c \\
        c & c & c & c \\
        c & c & c & c \\
        c & c & c & c
    \end{bmatrix}
    \) \\
\addlinespace
    Another line &
    That is like the one above. &
    \(
    \begin{bmatrix}
        a & a & a & a \\
        a & a & a & a \\
        a & a & a & a \\
        a & a & a & a
    \end{bmatrix}
    \begin{bmatrix}
        b & b & b & b \\
        b & b & b & b \\
        b & b & b & b \\
        b & b & b & b
    \end{bmatrix}
    =
    \begin{bmatrix}
        c & c & c & c \\
        c & c & c & c \\
        c & c & c & c \\
        c & c & c & c
    \end{bmatrix}
    \)
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

I used `\addlinespace` of `booktabs` for getting a better separation between rows.

[image]

Comment: It's nice that the column stuff is centralized (all together), but is there a way to handle row spacing without having to pepper `\addlinespace` all through the table?  I wish I knew more about these column specifications, but I haven't found a good resource.  And it looks like the `@{}` just goes between the columns anyway, so I couldn't define custom column types.

Comment: @TravisBemrose Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean about custom column types. The problem of touching rows is due to the extremely big matrices. Instead of `\addlinespace` you could fix it with ``\\[<dimen>``, but it takes guessing the right value.

Comment: egreg, Please see my edit to the question above. I finally worked out that `\\[12pt] \hline \\[-10pt]` is about the only thing that gives the intended result, but I have to put this in between every row.  Do you know of a way where I can simply use \\ in both my outer and inner tables/matrices, and just by changing some global line, the row spacing in the outer table/matrix changes, but not the inner ones?

Comment: @TravisBemrose The edit shows a problem quite different from the one in the initial question. Please, revert and make a followup question.

Comment: Different? I'm arranging tables within tables, and want to easily alter the spacing of the outer ones without altering the inner ones.